# Entity Framework WCF

Tags: jquery, wcf, entity-framework

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public List<DataModal.Employee> GetCustomers()
```

I want to return list of employee which is Entity Model object type.
How they can be serialize by default or need to write some code.
I am using jquery.

Comment: Did you try just returning a list of `DataModel.Employee`? That way, you'd see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `[DataContract]` attributes on your entity classes, and `[DataMember]` attributes on every property or field you want to have serialized. That's the standard way of doing thing in WCF. Once you do that, you can serialize your `List<Employee>` across a WCF service call.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Entity Framework 4 POCO objects? If not I do not think that this is going to work, or altleast not work well.

I would recommend that you create Data Transfer Objects marked with DataContract and DataMember, then use [auto mapper](http://www.codeplex.com/AutoMapper) to map the objects.